# Using draggable functionality with onClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I make a DIV degradable by the use of an image.

This is my code:

```
var tDV = 0;
$("#aTx").click(function() {
    var diagonalScl;
    var txSiz;
    tDV++;
    $("#ltn").append('<div id="aTextDV'+tDV+'></div>');
    $("#aTextDV"+tDV)
    .append('<div class="txmoPos" id="mvTx" onclick="mTxt(\'aTextDV'+tDV+'\')"><img src="img/img1.png"/></div>')
});
function mTxt(mndM){
    $("#"+mndM).draggable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is quote error in your `onclick` attribute value,

It should be like this

```
 $("#aTextDV"+tDV).append("<div class='txmoPos' id='mvTx' onclick='mTxt(\"aTextDV"+tDV+"\")'><img src=''/></div>")
```

[Check the Working Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3X6J7/2/)